# Хорошая ли практика использования Iframe для всего контента сайта, кроме шапки?

Tags: html, html5, css

Таким образом, шапка никогда не перегружается, а только контент

Comment: я всегда почему-то наивно думал, что для частичной перезагрузки страницы нужно использовать ajax

Comment: Не хорошая, большинство современных обозревателей кешируют не только изображения, но и повторяющиеся участки на страницах доменов.

Comment: Не вижу никакого смысла в подобных извращениях. Шапка сайта редко бывает тяжелой (иначе это уже не шапка), и плюс ко всему ее также нужно обновлять (редко какая шапка не зависит от содержимого страницы).

Comment: Покажите мне хоть один хороший пример сайта с фреймами!? Спец.сайты (по типу jsfiddle не в счет, хотя и там насколько помню не фреймы).

Их давно стоит изъять из употребления!

Comment: Когда вы ползаете по ссылкам во фрэйме, в адресной строке браузера ничего не меняется. Т.е. пользователь не знает, где он находится и в банальной ситуации, просто не сможет поделиться ссылкой с другом или сохранить страницу в закладки. Ну а поисковики будут индексировать тот сайт, что во фрэйме и отправлять на него.